# REST Api dealing with metadata, CreatedOn etc

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

When developing a REST Api what is the best way to deal with what I call object level metadata, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn etc?

A typical class might be:

```
public class Person {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set}
    public Guid CreatedBy {get; set;}
}
```

I used to think in an ideal world REST http methods would be mapped directly to controller methods, like:

```
public void Post (Person person) {
    ...perform the logic to add a person.
}
```

So the consumer of your API could theoretically post:

```
{
     "Id": "...guid...",
     "FirstName": "Joe",
     "LastName" : "Bloggs",
     "CreatedOn" : "01/01/12",
     "CreatedBy" : "...guid..."
}
```

However it doesn't sit right with me the consumer settings the Id, CreatedOn and CreatedBy. I don't think it's the responsibility of the consumer to do this. So this would leave me doing in my `Post` method:

```
public void Post (Person person) {
     person.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     person.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
     person.CreatedBy = ...get user credentials from request...
}
```

So the consumer is then free to post through:

```
{
     "FirstName": "Joe",
     "LastName" : "Bloggs"
}
```

What if we want to do an update using the Put method? Well this leaves us with the same problem, that if I don't want (or trust) the consumer to pass through this metadata then it leaves me having to do this in my `Put` method:

```
public void Put (Person person) {
     Person existingPerson = myRepository.GetEmployee(person.Id);

     existingPerson.FirstName = person.FirstName;
     existingPerson.LastName = person.LastName;

     myRepository.Save(existingEmployee);         
}
```

I'm starting to wonder if there is any real point to deserializing the consumers json/xml to a model object and passing through the `Post (Person person` or `Put (Person person)` because I am getting the slimmest of benefits from it. Why not just deserialize everything to a Dictionary (although only really viable for json)?

Am I missing something fundamental about REST? Is it normal to potentially deserialize an Id and 1 property to a model object, then retrieving the full object and updating it? Should I be forcing my consumer to pass through everything every time and then validating it?

I love the idea that the consumer passes through a chunk of json or xml and by the time it reaches my controller I'm just dealing with an object. It just seems a bit messy all this ignoring properties and pre-fetching existing records for update etc. Unless I am fundamentally misunderstanding REST?

Answer (score 1):

The design options that you're considering with aren't specific to REST, in my opinion, but apply to service design in general.  The way I read this, the base question would seem to be- who is responsible for the business logic that populates those fields, the caller or the service?

For my two cents, I see that as the responsibility of the server for two reasons.  First and foremost - security.  Client-side script is insecure by nature and therefore should not be trusted.  For example, a motivated individual could easily fake your audit trails and make it seem as if another user performed the action.  Second, I see the population of the audit/id fields as logic that cross-cuts the actual business purpose of the method being called.  In order to create a person, the client shouldn't have to be aware of the implementation details for how an id is represented.

As for using a dictionary versus a model, I see that as a personal preference.  Neither approach forces the client to pass the full set of fields.  Both would support a design in which the client passes in the only the primary set of fields for an operation.  Materialization into the model or a dictionary would simply be missing your audit/id fields.  Likewise, neither approach eliminates the need to validate the read-only fields on the server side, as there is no guarantee they were not changed on the client.

Comment: I agree with the servers responsibility to police entity level metadata. My point is more from where you have a setup like MVC 4's WebAPI that resolves the incoming json/xml to an object and calls the method passing that object in. It just feels a bit messy to half create this object and then tinker with the details. Maybe I'm missing the point...

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something?  The same data would be coming from the client no matter the server-side representation.  The way I see it, platform neutral, there are a couple of ways to represent this:  1) the standard collection of name/value pairs as part of the request data,  2) A hash set of name/value pairs parsed from the request data,  3) A model with fields materialized from the request data.   At the end of the day, its the same information just represented differently.  My personal preference is #3, simply because it saves me from having to populate a model from the name/value data.